# Dropping pins on MKMapView while UITableView is scrolling, obtaining coordinates from cell at certain screen position. Make pins "dance."

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, uiscrollview

Context and summary of what I'm attempting:

- I have a UIViewController containing an MKMapView and a child UITableView.
- Each cell in the table view contains a set of coordinates.
- I want a pin to drop on the map at the coordinates contained in the top cell.
- I want the pins to drop "in real time" as the table view is scrolling. When a cell reaches a certain y-axis screen position, a pin drops at its map coordinates, and when it leaves this y-position, the pin goes away to be replaced by a new pin at the next cell's map coordinates.
- The desired effect is to have the pins rapidly disappearing and reappearing (one at a time) at different locations on the map as the table view is scrolling. I call this "dancing."
- I would prefer not to have the cells get selected at the y-position, because I need to use the didSelectRow method for pushing to a new view controller.

You can see and run my attempted solution by copying and pasting the code I have into a new project.

I tried to solve this by using the `scrollViewDidScroll` method that gets called repeatedly when the table view is scrolling. I have it set up so that each time it is called, it gets the index path of the cell at the top of the table view, and if this index path is different than it was the last time the method was called (meaning a new cell has hit the top), a custom method `newPinFromScrolling` gets called. This method is supposed to remove the pin from the last top cell and drop a new one on the map at the coordinates specified in the new top cell.

I'm thinking that the two methods methods mentioned above would be the most relevant for anyone trying to figure this out. My`ViewDidLoad` is mostly groundwork, but I tried to put in some explanatory comments anyway.

I have nothing in my ViewController.h

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "AnnotationClass.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MKMapViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UITableView * myTableView;
    NSMutableArray * coordinatesArray;
    MKMapView * mapView;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerLocation;
    NSIndexPath * topRowIndexPath;
    NSIndexPath * oldRowIndexPath;
    UILabel * indexPathLabel;

    UIView * labelContainerView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //basic positioning stuff
    labelContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
    labelContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:labelContainerView];

    indexPathLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, 20, 50, 30)];
    indexPathLabel.text = @"0";
    [labelContainerView addSubview:indexPathLabel];

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 50)/2) + 50, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 50)/2) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [myTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 50)/2)];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    coordinatesArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

    //random location to drop pins around
    centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.72012665, -101.59623681);

    //way of getting 25 random locations around the center location
    for(int i=0;i<25;i++) {
        CGFloat latDelta = rand()* .99/RAND_MAX - 0.02;
        CGFloat lonDelta = rand()* .99/RAND_MAX - 0.08;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D cellCoordinate = {centerLocation.latitude+latDelta, centerLocation.longitude+lonDelta};

    //adding these coordinates to the table view array
        [coordinatesArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:cellCoordinate]];
    }

    //dropping all the pins on the map before any scrolling happens
    for ( int i=0; i<[coordinatesArray count]; i++)
    {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinates = [[coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i] MKCoordinateValue];

        AnnotationClass * dropPin = [[AnnotationClass alloc] init];
        dropPin.coordinate = annotationCoordinates;

        [mapView addAnnotation:dropPin];

    }

    //set our viewing region
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerLocation, MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.5, 2.5));
    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];




}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return coordinatesArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D cellCoordinate = [[coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] MKCoordinateValue];


    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", cellCoordinate.latitude, cellCoordinate.longitude];

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = myTableView.contentOffset;
    //the line below gets the index path of the cell located at the y coordinate of the table view's origin (the cell touching the top)
    topRowIndexPath = [myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:offset];

    //offset.y > 0 because indexpath = null when offset is less than 0
    if (topRowIndexPath != oldRowIndexPath && offset.y > 0) {
      //this method gets called every time the index path changes  
    [self newPinFromScrolling];

    //this label gets updated in real time
        indexPathLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",topRowIndexPath.row];
       }

    //oldRowIndexPath gets compared to topRowIndexpath next time this method is called
    oldRowIndexPath = topRowIndexPath;
}

- (void)newPinFromScrolling {
//remove previous pins. This seems to happen "in real time" too.
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];

    //below is all the code needed to drop a new pin on the map at the coordinates specified in the topmost cell. Some or all of it does not get called during the scroll event.
CLLocationCoordinate2D newPinCoordinates = [[coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:topRowIndexPath.row] MKCoordinateValue];

 AnnotationClass * newPin = [[AnnotationClass alloc] init];
newPin.coordinate = newPinCoordinates;
//An NSLog of newPin.coordinate shows that the pin coordinates get updated in real time.

  //It seems that this line here is the one that does not get called until the table view stops.
[mapView addAnnotation:newPin];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**AnnotationClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationClass : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate;

@end
```

**AnnotationClass.m**

```
#import "AnnotationClass.h"

@implementation AnnotationClass

-(void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    _coordinate = newCoordinate;
}

@end
```

Results:

- The `newPinFromScrolling` *does* get called "in real time" as the table view is scrolling.
- However the new pins *do not* drop in real time as the table view is scrolling. They only drop when the table view comes to a complete stop.
- I made a label that *does* update in real time each time the index path of the top cell changes, so I'm guessing the phone's ability to update in real time as the table view scrolls depends on the complexity of the task.

Conjecture:
 I thought that maybe if the table view were scrolling fast enough, the phone would not be able to complete the tasks necessary to drop a pin in time before the top cell got replaced, but it doesn't seem to matter at all how fast I'm  scrolling. *As long as the table view is in motion, the pins won't get dropped, even if it's scrolling slow enough for the task to be completed.* It's almost as if these tasks get disabled during the scroll event.

If that's the case, would there be any way to force the phone to attempt to complete the tasks in the `newPinFromScrolling` method? Could they be done in a separate thread, with a way of canceling threads that don't have time to complete when the table view is scrolling too fast? If that were arranged, then I would begin to look at ways of slowing down the scroll speed of the table view, so that the "dance" would be uninterrupted.

Comment: You won't be able to update UI from any thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Hey thanks, that just helped me out with something else.

Comment: Ha one thing down. Still thinking about this MKAnnotation thing

Comment: I figured it out by accident. Turns out changing the pin coordinate is all that needs to be done to make the position change on screen.

Comment: Nice! Well done. Answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out all that needs to be done to change the pin position is change its coordinate (just make sure it's already added to the map). Adding it and removing it every time the index path changed was unnecessary.